# Why generic type parameter get method throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, generics, nullpointerexception

I have this simple Java class and I am just trying to pass the Type but I get always a Nullpointer Exception cause null is obviously Null WHY?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Box<String> test = new Box<>();
    test.print();
    }


//And the Generic Class
public class Box<T> {
    // T stands for "Type"
    private T t;

    public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }
    public T get() { return t; }

    public void print () {

        System.out.println(this.t.getClass());
    }
}
```

Using JDK 12

Comment: You have to set your String before you can access it.

Answer (score 2):

You get NullPointerException because reference of t variable is null. You are trying to access the variable before initialize it. Firstly, call the setter method. Then try to get it.

> NullPointerException: NullPointerException Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required.

Here is the solution

```
Box<String> test = new Box<>();
test.set("hi!");
test.print();
```

Answer (score 1):

Whilst all other answers explain why you get the `NullPointerException`, it's clear you want to retrieve, one way or another, the `String` bit of your `Box<String>` expression.

You can't; this is called erasure. Generics in expressions and local variable declarations are figments of the compiler's imagination; they are compiler-checked comments. Like comments. they cease to exist at runtime.

Generics in *signatures* (so, method return types, parameter types, types of fields, and any generics mentioned anywhere in your class declaration line, so, the A, B, and C in `class Foo<A> extends Parent<B> implements Something<C>`) are recoverable using some very tricky and weird API (and you really don't want to, I think).

If you must be able to access single simple types, I suggest passing in the actual class object: `new Box<String>(String.class)`.

Answer (score 1):

You only new a Object `Box<String>` ,however you didn't initialize the `private T t;`
try something like this

```
Box<String> test = new Box<>();
test.set("the first way");
test.print();
```

or

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Box<String> test = new Box<>("the second way");
test.print();
}


public class Box<T> {
// T stands for "Type"
private T t;

public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }
public T get() { return t; }
public Box(T t) {this.t = t}
public void print () {

    System.out.println(this.t.getClass());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You only initialize your `Box<String>` object, but you didn't set the `T t` instance variable to anything.

As T is an Object its default value will be null.

Try setting it first, then calling print.

```
Box<String> test = new Box<>();
test.set("test");
test.print();
```